# AWS Lambda Javascript SDK when I get an error with the IAM sdk the callback is set to undefined

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

AWS Lambda Javascript SDK when I get an error with the IAM SDK the callback is set to undefined. When there is an error with the iam.listAttachedUserPolices call I get an error with the callback. If there is not an error I dont get this callback error. Any ideas?

```
TypeError: callback is not a function at Response



'use strict';
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
apiVersion: '2012-10-08',
    region: process.env.DDB_REGION || 'us-east-1'
});

let utils = require('utils');

module.exports.lab1 = (event, context, callback) => {

...

let params = {
    ...
    }
};

let iam:any;
try {
    iam = new AWS.IAM({
        accessKeyId: access_key,
        secretAccessKey: secret_key,
        region: process.env.DDB_REGION || 'us-east-1'
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', e)
    console.log('Failed verification 1');
    utils.lab(ddb, false ,cogid, callback);
    return;
}



ddb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('CALLBAKC TYPE1 ', typeof callback);
        utils.error(500,  "Failed to create user." + err, callback );
    } else {

        let iam_params = {
            UserName: 'test_user', /* required */
        };
        iam.listAttachedUserPolicies(iam_params, function (err2, data) {
                context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
                if (err2) {
```

// IF we get an error here callback shows up //undefined in the utils function. if we don't it shows up as a function.

```
                    console.log('Failed verification 4');

                    console.log(err2, err2.stack);
                    console.log('CALLBAKC TYPE2 ', typeof callback);
```

callback undefined here but in the success case it is a function

```
    utils.lab(ddb, false, cogid, callback); 
                }
                else {
                    ...
```

success case works

```
              }
       });
    }
 });
 };
```

Comment: Did you `"use strict";`?  If not, that's the first thing you need, and the problem may become obvious.  Otherwise, you'll need to show more of your code.  From just what you've shown here, the answer is obvious enough -- `callback` hasn't been assigned a value.  Presumably it's assigned a value somewhere... or you believe that it has... but we can't see it.

Comment: Updated the question with more code.

Comment: What is `utils`?  It doesn't appear to be [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utils).

Comment: It is a utility function that saves data in dynamo and uses the callback.

Comment: That seems the likely location for the bug, at the moment, because simply passing an undefined value wouldn't throw an error.  The error occurs when you try to invoke the callback.  Log `typeof callback` immediately after `console.log('Failed verification 1');`.  It should not be undefined.